# jasmine code for document.getElementById("username").focus()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am facing below error

> Typerror : can not read property focus of `null`

Sample source code

```
myapp.controller ('MyController',fucntion ($scope){
  document.getElementById("userame").focus();
  ....
});
```

Please suggest jasmine code for `document.getElementById()...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue Resolved. Please find sample code below.

describe('MyController',function(){

```
    var $location,$rootScope,$http,$window,LoginObj,scope;
    beforeEach(inject(
            function( _$location_,_$rootScope_,_$http_,_$window_,_LoginObj_) {
                $location = _$location_;
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                $http = _$http_;
                $window=_$window_;
                LoginObj = _LoginObj_;
           }));
    it('history.go(1) ',function(){
        //creating dummy element for html element 
        var dummyElement = document.createElement('div');
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); 

        document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(dummyElement);
        var controller = $controller('MyController',{
            $scope : $scope
        });
        //checking the focus of username
        spyOn(document.getElementById("username"),'focus');
        expect(document.getElementById("username").focus).toBeDefined();
```